# Unable to display form corrrectly with nested form array in a form group

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form group -> form group -> form array:

```js
      ngOnInit() {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
          dropDownOptions: this.fb.group({
            items: this.fb.array([this.createItem()])
          })
        })
      }

      createItem() {
        return this.fb.group({
          name: ['Jon'],
          surname: ['Doe']
        })
      }
```

In the mark up i'm unable to display the forms correcty as i'm getting the error:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'items' at _throwError (shared.ts:140)...

I thought i could easily get the data using:

```js
    get dropDownOptions(): FormArray {
       return (this.form.controls['dropDownOptions'] as FormArray).controls['items']
     }
```

Then in my html use this:

```html
      <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
      <div formArrayName="items"
        *ngFor="let item of dropDownOptions.controls; let i = index">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <input formControlName='name'>
          <input formControlName='surname'>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I can't seem to fix it or get the correct combination to dispay the form array items without an error!

Any ideas?

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7ce8l)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have created formGroup Inside another formGroup you need to use formGroupName directive

**Try this:**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
 <ng-container formGroupName="dropDownOptions">
    <div formArrayName="items"
    *ngFor="let item of dropDownOptions.controls; let i = index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <input formControlName='name'>
      <input formControlName='surname'>
    </div>
  </div>
 </ng-container>

  <button type="button" (click)="addNext()">Add Next</button>
  <button type="submit">Submit (look at console)</button>
</form>
```

Forked Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rsqgkg

Comment: Ok i get it now, so for every nested form group it requires the form group name, thanks